# Parse.com Twitter login on Android

Tags: android, twitter, parse-platform

I use this code for Twitter login on Android using [parse.com](http://parse.com)

```
Parse.initialize(this, "zzzzz", "zzzzz");
ParseTwitterUtils.initialize("zzzz","zzzzz");
ParseTwitterUtils.logIn(this, new LogInCallback()
{
            @Override
            public void done(ParseUser user,ParseException err)
            {
                if (user == null)
                {
                    Log.d("MyApp","Uh oh. The user cancelled the Twitter login.");
                }
                else if (user.isNew())
                {
                    Log.d("MyApp","User signed up and logged in through Twitter!");

                }
                else
                {
                    Log.d("MyApp", "User logged in through Twitter!"+user.toString());
                }
            }
        });
```

The login is OK and I look in the backend and there is my twitter account. How can I obtain this data in my Android App?

Thanks!

Comment: exactly what data do you want to obtain?

Comment: hi i did same code but its not showing login. can you help

Answer (score 6):

This line do the magic

**ParseTwitterUtils.getTwitter().getScreenName()**